# Authorization by ActivePivot

Tags: authorization, olap, activepivot

When I try to navigate at http://localhost:8080/content/rest/v4/files/ui/version?recursive=-1&metadata=false I have an error 404 (file not found).
While debugging I can see ActivePivot tries to define is my account granted for /ui/version.
It happens based on hibernate query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ent FROM AuditableCSEntry ent JOIN FETCH ent.startAction startAct WHERE path=:path AND ent.endAction IS NULL
```

So I suspect the authorization should be configured. But I could not find any mentions that. Does anyone hear about configuration steps for AP authorization?

Answer (score 0):

*http://localhost:8080/content/rest/v4/files/* targets the endpoint listing files stored in the Content Service.
The file *ui/version* is a file used by ActiveUI to detect how it is setup. It is initialized by ActiveUI itself, upon the first connection of an admin user.

This initialization process is described in the [online documentation](https://activeviam.com/activeui/documentation/4.3.4-rc//dev/advanced/content-server-setup.html#__docusaurus).
Basically, having an admin user connect to your ActiveUI application should be enough.